# Have any comic book villains tried a plan like Ultron's before?

Tags: marvel, dc, comics

In ***Age of Ultron***, Ultron's ultimate goal was to:

> Create an extinction level event by raising a massive chunk of earth high into the sky and dropping it.

Are there any examples of villains in either the Marvel or DC comic book universes trying to accomplish the same goal by the same means?

Comment: I wish you had finished going through with this question.

Answer (score 6):

At first, this would seem to be a pretty unique situation...

Vandal Savage tried to drop an asteroid on the Earth.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandal_Savage

...but then I realized it was actually a trope, called Colony Drop.

> In Green Lantern Corps v2 #13, the living planet Mogo intentionally
>   moves into the path of an asteroid to get rid of a sentient
>   space-fungus that's infected its forests. ◦ Then, in the conclusion of
>   the Sinestro Corps War, John Stewart and Guy Gardner get the idea to
>   take the newly recreated Warworld and throw it on top of the goddamn
>   Anti-Monitor.
>
> In the Justice League story "Terror Incognita" the Martian Manhunter
>   is confronting dozens of powerful White Martians on the Moon after
>   those same White Martians have all but conquered Earth. While The
>   Manhunter has them distracted the rest of the Justice League pulls the
>   moon toward Earth so that the entry into the atmosphere will burn the
>   Martians to nothingness if they do not surrender and enter the Phantom
>   Zone. Spell Casters cast a massive spell to keep the gravity of the
>   Moon from destroying Earth, and the Justice League (after imprisoning
>   the surrendering White Martians) pulls the moon away from Earth before
>   it can impact and destroy the planet.
>
> In an issue of The Spectacular Spider-Man in the 90's, Spidey and the
>   original X-Men teamed-up against Professor Power who was in control of
>   a floating castle. They defeat him and his Mooks but the castle is
>   sent plummeting toward New York. Obviously, they stop it just in time.

...and here goes the rest of your day:
http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ColonyDrop